# Nodejs process.argv[2] is omitting data after space even with \ when run through bash script

Tags: node.js, bash, arguments

So I have a node script that takes an argument, if I run the node script alone then something like `game\ of\ thrones` the entire string is considered `process.argv[2]` which is what I wanted and expected, the problem is when I run a very small bash script called `add` which consists of

```
#!/bin/bash

echo `nodejs ~/Codes/localHost/node/headsUp/add.js $1`
```

and then run `./add game\ of\ thrones` now `process.argv[2]` is only `game` why is this? if at all possible I would love to have a solution that allows me to put spaces between arguments to have multiple arguments rather than use something like `$@`. Thanks in advance. Oh and when I `echo $1` in the bash script it does come up as the full `game of thrones`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fail to quote `$1`, you are telling bash to resplit the parameter into words. In order to pass `$1` (or any other parameter or variable) verbatim into another script or binary, you need to make sure it is quoted:

```
echo `nodejs ~/Codes/localHost/node/headsUp/add.js "$1"`
```

Note that the output from `nodejs` will also be word-split, since it is not quoted. If you wanted to preserve formatting (such as newlines), you would need to quote that as well:

```
echo "$(nodejs ~/Codes/localHost/node/headsUp/add.js "$1")"
```

Here I changed the deprecated backtick syntax into the recommended `$(...)` syntax, which nests better.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It feels very 'workaroundish' which makes me feel like there is a better way but for those who may need to have this working you can concatenate your `process.argv` variable. using this method you can run your script and give it multiple arguments separated by spaces (actual spaces not spaces prefaced with `\`)

```
function conCatArgs(input){
var args = [];
for(i = 0; process.argv.length - 2 > i; i++){
    args[i] = input[i + 2]
}
console.log(args);
}

conCatArgs(process.argv);
```